# What should we infer from the final image in Sleight?

Tags: plot-explanation, sleight

The low budget indie movie [Sleight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4573516/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) is centred around Bo, a young character whose parents have died leaving him to look after his little sister.

He does this by performing street magic and dealing drugs.

He clearly performs some amazing (but typical) street magic tricks. But he also seems to perform some apparently impossible tricks. Early in the movie hints are given that these are not impossible but facilitated by some electromagnetic implant in his arm (not that this makes any sense form a physics point of view as an electromagnet wouldn't support most of them).

Later in the movie he appears to upgrade his device so he can fight back against his drug supplier and he is able to manipulate people, a baseball bat and a gun. all, apparently, because of his device.

But, right at the end of movie, his girlfriend Holly wakes at night and opens the door of his room. We see a white glow in her face and an expression of incredulity about what she sees (and we don't see what she sees). The movie ends.

What are we supposed to infer from that last scene? Are his powers *real* superpowers and not just the result of a scientific device? Does this explain why he could do things that don't make sense given the supposed scientific nature of his device?

Comment: Compulsory TV Tropes link [Maybe Magic, Maybe Mundane](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MaybeMagicMaybeMundane) ;)